# How to bind a Backbone.View to a 'single' DOM element in a list of similar elements in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have the following page structure:

```
<ul class="listOfPosts">
   <li class="post WCPost" data-postId="1">
      <div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="wcCheckbox"/></div>
      <div class="PostContainer>
       <!-- some other layout/content here -->
       <ul class="listOfLabels">
          <li class="label"> Label 1</li>
          <li class="label"> Label 2</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="post WCPost" data-postId="2">...</li>       
   <li class="post WCPost" data-postId="3">...</li>
   <li class="post WCPost" data-postId="4">...</li>
   ...
</ul>
```

Here is the overly simplistic View:

```
  var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$('.listOfPosts'),

    initialize: function() {
         _.bindAll(this,"postClicked");
    },

    events: {
        "click .wcCheckbox":"postClicked"
    },

    postClicked: function() {
         alert("Got a a click in the backbone!");
        }
  });
```

Question: I want to know the data Id of post that was clicked. With simple JQuery I can just do the following:

```
$('.wcCheckbox').live('click' function() {
    alert("Data id of post = "+$(this).parents('.WCPost').data('data-postId'));
}
```

Now I know that Backbone does event delegation so it needs a DOM reference in the el property. If I give it the .listOfPosts then the event seems to fire perfectly but to get "which" posts were checked I'll have to keep traversing the DOM and pick out the elements that were selected!!! It would be quite expensive in my opinion! How do I do this in Backbone for each individual post?? i.e., How do I bind the view to each individual li.WCPost??

NOTE: I'm not using plain vanilla jQuery since the code that I need to write is best done with Backbone's modular design, but since I'm not a pro with Backbone (yet ;) just a bit confused...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using something like `$(event.target).data('postId')` in your `postClicked()` function is a normal way to do this kind of stuff, as far as I can tell.

Extensive usage of events might seem unusual at first, but it's a good way to improve code organization, if used properly. You really can get all the data you want from the event in most cases, especially if you have jQuery. (Note that the event passed to your `postClicked` function is a regular jQuery event object, and [everything you can find about it](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+event&hl=en&qscrl=1) could be applied. Backbone.js [uses](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents) jQuery's `delegate()` function to bind events.)

* * *

However, you still can bind events by yourself in the `initialize()` method of your view.

```
initialize: function() {
     // Custom binding code:
     this.$('.wcCheckbox').live('click' function() {
         alert("Data id of post = "+$(this).parents('.WCPost').data('data-postId'));
     }
     // No need for this anymore:
     // _.bindAll(this,"postClicked");
},
```

(`this.$(<selector>)` is a function that automatically scopes jQuery selectors to your view, equivalent to `$(<selector>, this.el)`.)

* * *

Another solution (perhaps the most natural in the end, however requiring a bit of work at first) is to create a `PostView` class, and use it for individual posts and for binding checkbox click event.

To display the posts, in your post list view you go through `Posts` collection, create a view for each `Post` instance, and append it to the `.listOfPosts` element.

You won't need to solve a problem of accessing post's ID anymore, since you would bind the checkbox click event on a `PostView`. So, in the handler function would be able to find post's ID easily—either through related model (`this.model.get('id')`) or through view's element (`$(this.el).data('postId')`).

#### * * * **Update**

> Now that I generated my posts' DOM independently of Backbone how do I 'retrofit' a view to each post like I mentioned in the question?
>
> I don't want to refactor a ton of client code just to accommodate Backbone. But how do I bind a view to each li??

If you decided to go with MVC and object-oriented JavaScript, you shouldn't manage DOM elements for your posts directly: you create `PostView` instances, and they, in turn, create corresponding elements, like in todos.js, and fill them with rendered template. (And if you don't want to create elements automatically, Backbone allows you to bind newly created view to the element manually, by specifying `el` attribute when subclassing. This way, you can bind views to existing elements, for example, on the initial page load.) Any DOM modification related to particular posts should take place inside the `PostView` class.

Some advantages of OOP approach over DOM-based:

- Views are more suitable for data storage than DOM elements.

  Note that with your current approach you're using `data` attributes extensively—for example, to store post's ID. But you don't need to do that if you're operating views: each `PostView` already knows about its related model, and so you can easily get the post id via, e.g., `view.model.get('postId')`, as well as any other post data that you want.

  You can also store *view-specific data* that doesn't belong to Post model: for example, animation and / or display state (expanded, selected, …).
- Views are more suitable for defining the behaviour of elements.

  If you want to, for example, specify a checkbox click event handler for each post, you place this code into your `PostView` class. This way, *event handler knows about all post data*, because the view has access to it. Also, *the code is better structured*—what deals with particular posts, belongs to `PostView`, and doesn't get in your way.

  Another example is a convention to define a `render()` function on the view. The template function or template string is stored in a view attribute `template`, and `render()` renders that template and fills the view's element with resulting HTML:

  ```
  render: function() {
      $(this.el).html(this.template({
          modelData: this.model.toJSON()
      }));
  },
  ```
- Manipulating DOM may be slower than manipulating objects.

**However**, DOM-based approach (which seems like you were using until now) has its own pros, especially for less complicated applications. See also: [Object Oriented Javascript vs. Pure jQuery and .data storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3993545/247441)

> Is there a way to bind views to current and future DOM elements that are NOT generated by backbone?
>
> Does that imply that backbone needs to be use from the very start and will be difficult to 'retrofit' so to speak?

As follows from above, you don't need to bind views to *future* DOM elements (use views to manipulate them).

Regarding binding to the DOM elements that are already on the page when it's initialized, I don't know the ‘right’ way to do that. My current approach is to clear existing elements and create views from scratch, which would automatically create corresponding DOM elements.

This means browser will have some extra work to do at page initialization. For me, advantages of OOP justify it. From the user's point of view, it's also fine, I guess: after that initial initialization, everything will work faster, since page won't need to be reloaded until user does something like logout.

(BTW, I think I should clarify the point of using MVC approach, at least, for me: creating a client-side application that, essentially, does the most work by itself, using the API provided by the back-end server. Server provides data in JSON for models, and your client-side app does the rest, extensively using AJAX. If you do normal page loads when user interacts with your site, then such MVC and heavy client-side might be overhead for you. Another thing is that you will have to refactor some code, which may not be an option depending on your requirements and resources.)

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies things quite a bit. The thing that is still confusing is this. Now that I generated my posts' DOM independently of Backbone how do I 'retrofit' a view to each post like I mentioned in the question? I guess I'll read up the link you posted as well as those by Brendan to come up to speed on the events part. My posts are not very trivial and I use a client side micro-template (non Underscore.js) to generate them. I don't want to refactor a ton of client code just to accommodate Backbone. But how do I bind a view to each li??

Comment: (Cont'd) You also mentioned it's the most natural thing to do but I'm still stuck on "how"?? Is there a way to bind views to current and future DOM elements that are NOT generated by backbone? Does that imply that backbone needs to be use from the very start and will be difficult to 'retrofit' so to speak? Can I have non-Backbone views listen to models/collections so if it is indeed difficult to do so with backbone, I could create custom "views" using jQuery! Just to let you know - I honestly appreciate your help and enjoy the insights that help me learn backbone better :)

Comment: Okay, that seems to make A LOT of sense. We decided to generate a good amount of data on the server using freemarker. We didn't choose pure JSON data interchange, but rather a form-based representation for submission of data. I now understand the design differences of OO-JS vs Jquery with data attributes. Makes so much sense :) Well the discovery is a bit late to change the design but that's what I call experience :) - the design is the way it is probably by the lack of it :) I'll make do with what I have and what I can accommodate given the constraints

Comment: I was guessing this to be the case (i.e., the explanation you gave) since intuitively that's how I was thinking of designing the application - A view per post. The fact that I was unable to do it post-facto caught me off guard and made me realize that there is probably a different way of doing things other than jquery/data-* attributes. I've NEVER looked at JS from an OO perspective but since you've pointed me to backbone I just can't help thinking about it :) I sincerely appreciate all the help/pointers. I may use a pure backbone/Json approach for other parts of the system and learn :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Can you ever set a data-* attribute of a view? I was unable to do this with view.make (I was trying this.make in the view) If backbone is used I guess you'll always 'route through it' and storing data in the class attributes makes more sense. But how can one assign data-* attributes to a view using backbone? Is this a no-no?? Didn't want to add another question, honestly :)

Comment: Well, if you're using templates, it makes sense to fill in data attributes as parts of a template, so they will be defined when you render the view. Of course, later you still can set `data-*` attribute on a view's element using jQuery, as usual—in your view method, you can do something like `$(this.el).data(...);` (where `this` refers to current view). What's `make`, is it a view's method? What approach did you use to set data-attributes there?

Answer (score 2):

Note that events pass reference to themselves and their point of origin, it's the easiest way to access the origination of the event, in my opinion.

Try it like this, and see if this is what you need (and less convoluted):

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el:$('.listOfPosts'),

    initialize: function() {
         _.bindAll(this,"postClicked");
    },

    events: {
        "click .wcCheckbox":"postClicked"
    },

    postClicked: function(e) {
        alert("Here is my event origin: "+e.target);
    }

});
```

There is a rich amount of data that can be had from the event, as can be seen here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

once you get your head wrapped around javascript eventing, you might look into PubSub/Observer pattern for more-decoupled UI components, here is a good introduction:

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2011/01/loosely-coupled-javascript-using-pubsub/

Comment: Nice point there. I could go via the event's target, but won't I have to deal with browser incompatibilities just to get the "data-*" attribute of the traget/srcElement?? Isn't there any other way of binding events to individual <code><li>s</code> on a page? Isn't that a serious drawback of using backbone???

Comment: @Nupul, you can still use jQuery's `data()` method to handle all browser quirks for you: `alert("Got a click from: " + $(e.target).parent('.WCPost').data('postId'))`. (You would need to add an `e` argument to your `postClicked` function to access the event object like this.)

Comment: how complex is the data? if it is just an "id" - you could set it on the "id" property of the element, like `<li id="{generated id}"> blah blah </li>` - again, this will be using the core parts of HTML to do the work for you, instead of a convoluted approach - does this help?

Comment: @Brendan: Actually I have quite a bit of data-* tags. They are not only ids but quite a few other things. We chose this design approach and will be sticking with it for a while :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents you from nesting views.  That is, the outer view represents the UL.  The UL view would render a bunch of inner LI views.  You can nest views as deeply as makes sense.

I've been doing things this way very successfully.